# Similar Products don´t get grouped on review Page

Tags: commerce

When adding multiply quantities of the same product they don´t get grouped but splitted to each line on the overview checkout pane.

-Example-

Instead of:

> Product: PLAYSTATION QTY 3

It shows:

> Product: PLAYSTATION QTY 1
>
> Product: PLAYSTATION QTY 1
>
> Product: PLAYSTATION QTY 1

I know this is a view, I tried to configure it to grouping, but with no change.
Even this module did not help:
https://www.drupal.org/project/views_aggregator

What can I do to have all similar products grouped and sum quantity?

Comment: did you get it ? The solution is quite straight ;)

Comment: No, finally not, i found this configuration and it was set accordingly to the answer, but it made no change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to go to `admin/structure/types/manage/YOUR_DISPLAY_TYPE/display`, search for the *product field / add_to_cart form*
and set it to **combine like items : enabled**

That's it.

[image]

Comment: Thank you, but this configuration was set already. Sometimes it get grouped, sometimes not. Do you have any more ideas what to check?

Comment: Well, to be grouped, IMO each one of the product variations must be similar. Check carefully that point. At the moment I don't have another tip in my mind sorry :)

Comment: I meant product variation *values*, I guess you understood that point. If you have many fields like memory, platform, color ... whatever, if any value is different then products won't be grouped during checkout process

Comment: I don´t use variations and it happens on same products getting added. I will investigate if there is any difference or a rule is splitting it.